# Does $\int_a^b f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt$ depend on the path for meromorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Given a meromorphic function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ and a smooth curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Gamma\subset\mathbb C$ with $\gamma(a)\neq\gamma(b)$, I am tempted to think the fundamental theorem of calculus yields

$$\int_a^b\underbrace{f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt}_{=df} = f(\gamma(t))\Big|_{t=a}^b (*)$$

independently of the chosen path. However, taking a closed integral through both $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)\neq\gamma(a)$, the residue theorem $\oint f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt = 2\pi i\sum_k\operatorname{Res}_k(f')$ proves me wrong when the closed curve surrounds a singularity of $f'$ since the two paths connecting $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ would otherwise cancel out the residue. So now my question is:

What correction term needs to be added to $(*)$? Can that be fixed at all, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument using the fundamental theorem of calculus is correct. In fact, the residue of the derivative of a meromorphic function is zero at all its poles (which follows exactly from the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Another way to see it is to look at the Laurent series. If $f$ is holomorphic on a punctured disc $0 < |z-a| < r$, the only obstruction to $f$ having an anti-derivative is if the Laurent series has a non vanishing $(z-a)^{-1}$ term.

Comment: Silly me, of course Laurent series don't have a $\ln(z-a)$ term which would be required for a singularity of the derivative [m-/](http://picardfacepalm.com/) Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

The correction term can be given in terms of the [winding numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) $n(k,\gamma)$ of the directed curve $\gamma$ about the poles $k$ of $f$.  We have
$$\int_a^b f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) dt = f(\gamma(t)) \bigg\vert_{a}^b +2\pi i \sum_k n(k,\gamma)\mathrm{Res}_k(f').$$

Intuitively, the winding number counts how many times a curve wraps around a single point.  For simple closed curves, this number will always be $0$, $1$, or $-1$, depending on whether or not the curve encloses the given point, and what direction the parametrization is given in.  Note that this formula recovers the Residue theorem (these results are pretty much equivalent, if you throw some topology under the rug), if we suppose that $\gamma$ is a closed curve.

Comment: Hm, this sounds sensible, but what would the winding number for half such a curve be, and how to determine which residues the unclosed curve "encloses"?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that $\gamma(a)\neq\gamma(b)$, does your answer still make sense then?

Comment: Ah ok, if you sum over _all_ residues in $\mathbb C$ and take the more general winding number as $n(a_k,\gamma) = \frac1{2\pi}\int_a^b\theta'(t)\,dt$ where $\theta(t) = \arctan\frac{\Im(\gamma(t)-a_k)}{\Re(\gamma(t)-a_k)}$ (or similar) this might work. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I've been checking for references and I can't seem to find what I've been looking for.  I might have to delete this answer.  I know for a fact that the integral in question will evaluate to what you want, *up to an element of the period module* (i.e. up to an element of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by the contour integrals about a homology basis for the punctured domain of $f$).  As for choosing a representative, it's tough to say.  In some sense, you're choosing an analytic continuation of $f$ along $\gamma$, and while we can relate continuations, we know little about each one.

Comment: I'd appreciate you leaving the answer intact nonetheless - though [mrf'answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/509328/163) showed $\operatorname{Res}(k,f')\equiv 0$ for meromorphic functions, this still gives me an interesting idea on how to define a path-independent antiderivative $F(b) := F(a) + \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt - 2\pi i \sum_k n_k(\gamma)\operatorname{Res}_k(f)$ with the non-integer winding number for unclosed curves mentioned before...